# How do I assign contents of a string to a text field in Unity 4.6?

Tags: text, unity-game-engine

I am working on a C# class that imports text data from a web site. That works OK. Where I'm losing it is how to display the text in Unity 4.6 once I have all the text in a string variable. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity 4.6 UI system has component named `Text`. You can watch video tutorial [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-text). Also I suggest you to check out its [API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html).

As always, you have two options on how to add this component to the game object. You can do it from editor (just click on game object you want to have this component in hierarchy and add `Text` component). Or you can do it from script using `gameObject.AddComponent<Text>()`.

In case you are not familiar with components yet, I suggest you to read this [article](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingComponents.html).

Anyway, in your script you'll need to add `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the very top of it, because the `Text` class is in `UnityEngine.UI` namespace. Ok, so now back to script that will set the value of `Text` component.

First you need variable that refers to `Text` component. It can be done via exposing it to editor:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text myText;
    public void SetText(string text) {
        myText.text = text;
    }
}
```

And attaching gameObject with text component to this value in Editor.

Another option:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public void SetText(string text) {
        // you can try to get this component
        var myText = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        // but it can be null, so you might want to add it
        if (myText == null) {
            myText = gameObject.AddComponent<Text>();
        }
        myText.text = text;
    }
}
```

Previous script is not a good example, because `GetComponent` is actually expensive. So you might want to cache it’s reference:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {
    Text myText;
    public void SetText(string text) {
        if (myText == null) {
            // looks like we need to get it or add
            myText = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
            // and again it can be null
            if (myText == null) {
                myText = gameObject.AddComponent<Text>();
            }    
        }
        // now we can set the value
        myText.text = text;
    }
}
```

BTW, the patter of ‘GetComponent or Add if it doesn’t exist yet’ is so common, that usually in Unity you want to define function

```
static public class MethodExtensionForMonoBehaviourTransform {
    static public T GetOrAddComponent<T> (this Component child) where T: Component {
        T result = child.GetComponent<T>();
        if (result == null) {
            result = child.gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So you can use it as:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {
    Text myText;
    public void SetText(string text) {
        if (myText == null) {
            // looks like we need to get it or add
            myText = gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<Text>();
        }
        // now we can set the value
        myText.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I am using public Text someText  now and it is working great!

Answer (score 2):

make sure you import the ui library - `using UnityEngine.UI`

`gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text` - replace .text with any other field for UI Text

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the issue is creating dynamic sized "textbox" rather than just assigning the string to a GUIText GameObject. (If not - just put a GUIText GameObject into your scene, access it via a GUIText variable in your script and use myGUIText.text = myString in Start or Update.)

If I am correct in my assumption, then I think you should just be using a GUI Label:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html

If you need to split the string up to place text into different labels or GUITexts, you will need to use [substrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to use the GUI.Label in an ONGui function. What I am trying to do here is avoid ONGui and use the new GUI tools in Unity 4.6 to dynamically display text on the screen. I'm working on a function that displays imported text data from a web site, then parses the data to be inserted into a database. I have the import working, but not the text display part.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood. You should be able to access the documentation for the new features locally, but I dont think they are available online yet. (I could be wrong but I cant find it)

An example can be found in this video at around 20:21

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui

Comment: Not a problem. I have been studying the new features. One thing I forgot was to select the new Unity 4.6 UI resize icon on the top left of the screen before attempting to resize the text object. If I use the conventional resize icon, the fonts become huge when resizing the object.